# can any one help me with this jquery code , i want to console the array out side the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

```
 $('#list').click(function(){
                        var val = [];
                        $(':check box:checked').each(function(i){
                            val[i] = $(this).val();
                        });
                        console.log(val);

                    });
```

can any one help me with this jquery code , i want to console the array out side the loop  !! i tried so many options but ,no success ,please help me

i want to print the array out side the click function

Comment: So make `val` a global...

Comment: Shouldn't this `$(':check box:checked')` be this `$(':checkbox:checked')`

Comment: i want to console out side the loop    ' $('#list').click(function(){
                        var val = [];
                        $(':check box:checked').each(function(i){
                            val[i] = $(this).val();
                        });
                                  });             console.log(val); '

Answer (score 0):

As I said it in my comment, you need to make `val` so it is not a local variable. You can do that by moving its declaration outside of the closure.

```
val = [];
$('#list').click(function(){
    val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        val[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(val); 
});
```

Comment: @Nithishkumar this is the answer you're looking for to log it outside the click function.

Comment: i want to console outside the loop  and jquery

Comment: So you call console outside the loop and function. Code above will allow that. Just remember that you need to call the method somehow since just placing it outside will run when the code is hit the first time, it will not magically keep running.

Answer (score -1):

you can use map function

```
$("#list").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get(); // <----
    console.log(searchIDs);
});

see this fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fu5zy5x/

Comment: i want to console outside the loop and jquery